# magnific closeOnContentClick does not work

Tags: magnific-popup

I have the following in my initialisation code so that people can click on the image to dismiss the pop-up. But it isn't working. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});
$('.magnifierIcon').magnificPopup({ 
  type: 'image',
  image: {
    // options for image content type
    closeOnContentClick: true
  }           
    // other options
});
```

thanks
Derek

Now solved:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
    });
    $('.magnifierIcon').magnificPopup({ 
        type: 'image',closeOnBgClick: true,closeOnContentClick:true
        // other options
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`closeOnContentClick` is general option, not image option. So it should go after `type:image`, not inside `image:{}`.